# Understanding a part of SQL code with isnull

Tags: sql

I am not very expert in `SQL` but reading a small line obtained from another person. This line looks like below

```
isnull(case when mydate < @cutoff then [COL1] else [COLB] end, 0)
```

What is the significance of the part `end, 0` above?

Comment: ISNULL has two arguments. The first one here is a `case` _expression_, ending with an `end`. The second argument is `0`.

Comment: So if `case when mydate < @cutoff then [COL1] else [COLB]` is NOT NULL then return as-is, otherwise return `0` - is that what happening here?

Comment: Exactly. (However, I always use `coalesce` instead of isnull. Coalesce is SQL standard and portable, and takes an arbitrary number of arguments.)

Comment: What exactly from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of SQL will check the value of `mydate`. If it's less than `@cutoff`, it returns the value of `[COL1]`. If it's not, it returns the value of `[COLB]`. In either case, if the resulting value is `NULL`, it will return `0` instead. This can be particularly useful in situations where you need to ensure that the result of your query is not `NULL`, perhaps to avoid errors in calculations or further processing.